# Count up a variable in a while loop using EXEC

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have another question and hope u can help me!

I need a while loop in which I execute (EXEC) a command using a variable (here: @SETi) I defined before. Amongst others, the variable 'i' I use for the while loop has to be count up.

Here a very small piece of my code:

```
DECLARE @i int
SET @i = 1

DECLARE @SETi nvarchar(max)

WHILE @i <= 10

    BEGIN

        -- Tabelle definieren

        SET @SETi = 'SET '+CAST((@i) as nvarchar(max))+' += 1'

        EXEC (@SETi)

    END
```

First of all the loop isn't stopping.. And I get the warning: Incorrect syntax near '1'.

Why is that?

Thanks a lot!! T.R.

Comment: Tag dbms used! (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL at all...)

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: First of all you forgot "SET @i = @i +1" in your while loop, so it's endless. And when you add "print @SETi" before exec, you can see what you are doing wrong

Comment: The " SET @i = @i + 1 " is included in my EXEC command respectively in the variable @SETi.

Comment: @T.R., why are you using dynamic sql? Elaborate on what you want to do...

Comment: @T.R. it's not included, your "CAST((@i) as nvarchar(max))" will not have an output "SET @i = @i +1". Use a "print" to see it for yourself! And you can't exec it like this anyway, because EXEC will create a new query session, and the variable @i is not declared for it's session :-)

Comment: Just recoginzed that, thanks!

Comment: Ok, now my comment about what I want to do is gone.... So, again: I want to create a table in every cycle of the loop. The name of the table should include the value of @i, thats why I want to have a dynamic command. Thats why I also used CAST, but I now see why it doest make sense here!!! I thought I just execute one command including the loop, the creation of the table, inserting stuff in the table and counting up @i. But seems like that doenst work..

Answer (score 0):

Increment the variable in current context, because `EXEC` has its own and you can not access it from there:

```
DECLARE @i int = 1
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

WHILE @i <= 10
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = 'create table someName' + CAST(@i as nvarchar(max)) +...

        EXEC (@sql)

        SET @i = @i + 1
    END
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I know that your solution works, but I dont know if I can solve my problem w that..